# How can I display the selected element of a dropdown list in a button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this dropdown menu:

```
  <div class="input-group">

  <div class="input-group-btn">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">

    All Categories

    <span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-model = "cat">

      <li><a href="#">All Categories</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clothes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

What can I do to display the chosen element from the list instead of the label of the button which is "All Categories". Alternatively can I remove the label and just set the default selected item to be the first one, which is also "All Categories"?

Also, another question, how can I access the selected value in a JS file using angular?

```
$scope.cat.value
```

Doesnt seem to work.

Comment: can you post a fiddle? or the angular code?

Comment: Please post the second question as a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a $scope.selected variable in your angularjs code.Modify your list-item tags (options) adding **ng-click** from angularjs for setting the **selected** variable value. For example:

`<li ng-click="selected = 'option1'"><a>Option1</a></li>`

If you click it, then the **selected** variable will be assigned the value "option1".

Another option could be to call a function from angular code inside the ng-click:

`ng-click="selectItem('option1')"`

Then in angular code:

`$scope.selectItem = function(value) { $scope.selected = value; }`

If you want to get the value of your angular scope variables just do $scope.variable. In this case it will be $scope.selected

Comment: Both of those answers dont work. "cat" is a dropdown menu so when you set it equal to something, nothing happens. When I log $scope.cat it prints "undefined".

Comment: Add your angularjs code from where you are calling that $scope.cat. Also, where in your html code is your ng-app or ng-controller declared?

Comment: The problem is the angular code is way too long. I declare the ng-app and ng-controller in the beginning of the file. The controller is linked correctly because other things work, this is just a very small part of something a lot bigger.

Comment: I edited the answer to give you another option to try. Try console.log($scope.selected) just after it is set.